# How to send empty file in android Volley Multi-part along with the other headers

Tags: android, file, android-volley, multipartform-data, multipartentity

I am working on Volley Multipart to upload images to server.
for that I am using

```
mBuilder.addBinaryBody(headerKeyName, file, ContentType.create("image/jpg"),FILEPATH);
```

Now I have to send the empty file along with some headers.
how can I use that method for empty file.

Please someone help me.

Comment: You can create an empty file with File file = new File(some_path); file. createNewFile(); then send it to the web service.

Comment: @tabitoq  can You please send me the exact statement like Above I sent.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do something like this:

```
         File file = new File("path");

            try {  
              if (file.createNewFile()) {    
               mBuilder.addBinaryBody(headerKeyName, file,ContentType.create("image/jpg"), file.getAbsoluteFile());
              }
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Regards.

Comment: if file is null, then file path is also null right?

Comment: it is not working. getting **java.io.IOException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)**

Comment: please be sure that you have this permission enabled WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: android studio not accepting write internal storage permission in manifest

Comment: sorry , I mean WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, try to save that file on external storage.

Comment: I mean, My question is ,  First I didnot taken any capture from camera to upload to server. so at first file is null.